# padAngle function in d3 arc throwing error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I have below d3 pie chart code and its throwing error in console for padAngle function padAngle is not a function

```
var pie=d3.layout.pie()     
.value(function(d){return d.percent})
.sort(null)
.padAngle(0.2);
```

Comment: What version of `d3` are you using?

Comment: I am using d3.v3.min.js. I tried using d3.v4.min.js ,it throws pie not defined error in console.

Answer (score 1):

If i use the downloaded d3 file i am seeing the errors.If I am replacing src with url "https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" padAngle is working fine.